# Openssl sha256 does not give standard output

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to write a c++ code which converts a a string to sha256 encryption. I am using openssl library for encryption. But my output is not as same as standard output.Its length is less than 64.I am using linux and gcc compiler. I am using the code posted in this forum.
Please suggest  how to solve it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Length of sha256 digest is not 64. It should be 32 bytes (256 bits). (openssl does not usually return hex dump)